# Write jQuery variables to a file

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-io

I have used a jquery function to process a form which is given below.

```
$("#advertForm").submit(function(e)
{
  var url=$(target).attr('title');
  var imgname=$(target).attr('name');
  var Form = { };

  $.post('processAdvert.php', Form, function(data)
            {
               if(data == "Success")
                    {

                            setTimeout( function() {  location=url }, 2500 );
                            return;
                    }
            });
return false;
});
```

I need to write url and imgname to a text file. I know there is no way to write a file in jquery. Can I use any PHP function (fwrite) to write this variable into a file? How can I write this variable into a file?

Comment: This is *extremely* unsafe. Don't do it.

Comment: jQuery is client-side; PHP is server-side. You need to decide what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there any way to do that? In this form submit type as images. All images are submit button. I have to find the clicked image and store the information in a file.

Comment: @Blender please elaborate. If he never executes the file he writes into, what's the risk? moreover, he's not grabbing the variables from an url, either.

Comment: Are you trying to write to a file on the web server or on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that in some way. Send an ajax request to your php file. process your data, create a file, write some data using [fput() method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php), Use force download class that will allow you to download the file at that moment. Ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: Thank you Arun. I will try that way and let you know if I have any doubt.